# How do I extend one of my external hard drive's partitions to 50 GB of unallocated space?

Tags: partitioning

Please see the screenshots beneath. My goal is to add 50 GB to drive E (with 258 GB).

Initially I tried 1, but the 50 GB never appeared in the 'Extend Volume Wizard'.

Then I formatted the 50 GB as I didn't know what else to try, but  the 'Extend Volume'  greyed-out.

[image]

Comment: On a basic disk, you can only extend a volume to free space **following** it. In your screenshot 1, the only operation you could do was to extend the Windows7_OS volume by anything below 50GB.

Comment: What you want would require the partition be deleted then recreated.

Comment: @ChangQian Sorry, but what do you mean by "following it"? Does the alphabetical order of the drives matter?

Comment: @Ramhound Isn't that what I did in 2?

Comment: @Greek-Area51Proposal - No;  You have an allocated partition on both sides of the partition in question

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry if you already reviewed 1, and I'm overlooking something. But what about "unallocated" in 1? That's what happens when I delete A.

Comment: Why did you allocate a partition instead of simply extending the partition you want larger?  Extend is grayed out in the second half of your screenshot, due to the fact, there isn't unallocated space following the partition.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @Ramhound In 1, I did click 'Extend Volume', and the 'Extend Volume Wizard' appeared, as you can see. But as I wrote, "the 50 GB never appeared in the 'Extend Volume Wizard'."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82975/discussion-between-ramhound-and-greek-area-51-proposal).